# bash/sed/awk: change first alphabet in string to uppercase

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Let say I have this list:

```
39dd809b7a36
d83f42ab46a9
9664e29ac67c
66cf165f7e32
51b9394bc3f0
```

I want to convert the first occurrence of alphabet to uppercase, for example

39dd809b7a36 -> 39Dd809b7a36

bash/awk/sed solution should be ok.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi,

I found my own solution after playing with sed regex for a while.

The solution is

`sed 's/\([a-z]\)/\U\1/'`

sample:

`optimus:~# echo "96f795e4370a`
`> bfe6f5e05416`
`> 5f70a4463d79`
`> decab73017db`
`> a136f8c01c18`
`> " | sed 's/\([a-z]\)/\U\1/'`
`96F795e4370a`
`Bfe6f5e05416`
`5F70a4463d79`
`Decab73017db`
`A136f8c01c18`

Hopefully people will find it useful.

Other solutions is interesting as well. :)

Comment: I would expect this to work on most sed versions. surprised to hear OSX doesn't .... :> echo bfe6f5e05416 | sed 's/\([a-z]\)/\U\1/'
result=Bfe6f5e05416 ....:>sed --version  result=GNU sed version 4.2.1

Comment: yes. mine is GNU sed. optimus:~# sed --version
GNU sed version 4.1.5
this page mention that \U is GNU extension: [http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

Comment: @sharuzzaman-ahmat-raslan add your solution as a proper answer so it can be accepted and thus removed from the unanswered problems

Comment: @fredrik I cannot add yet because I just joined less than 6 hours ago. will add by tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure Bash 4.0+ using parameter substitution:

```
string=( "39dd809b7a36" "d83f42ab46a9"
         "9664e29ac67c" "66cf165f7e32" "51b9394bc3f0" )

for str in ${string[@]}; do
  # get the leading digits by removing everything
  # starting from the first letter:
  head="${str%%[a-z]*}"
  # and the rest of the string starting with the first letter
  tail="${str:${#head}}"
  # compose result : head + tail with 1. letter to upper case
  result="$head${tail^}"

  echo -e "$str\n$result\n"
done
```

Result:

```
39dd809b7a36
39Dd809b7a36

d83f42ab46a9
D83f42ab46a9

9664e29ac67c
9664E29ac67c

66cf165f7e32
66Cf165f7e32

51b9394bc3f0
51B9394bc3f0
```

Answer (score 4):

GNU sed can do it

```
printf "%s\n" 39dd809b7a36 d83f42ab46a9 9664e29ac67c 66cf165f7e32 51b9394bc3f0 |
sed 's/[[:alpha:]]/\U&/'
```

gives

```
39Dd809b7a36
D83f42ab46a9
9664E29ac67c
66Cf165f7e32
51B9394bc3f0
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any clever way to do this with the basic SW tools, but the BFI solution isn't *too* bad.

In the One True awk(1) or in gawk:

```
{ n = split($0, a, "")
  for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    s = a[i]
    t = toupper(s)
    if (s != t) {
      a[i] = t
      break
    }
  }
  r = ""
  for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    r = r a[i]
  }
  print r
}
```

It's not too bad in Ruby:

```
ruby -p -e '$_ = $_.split(/(?=[a-z])/, 2); $_[1].capitalize!'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. It will not allow patterns in form ###.### but can be tweaked as needed.

A=$(cat); B=$(echo $A | sed 's/([a-z])/###\1###/' | sed 's/.*###(.)###.*/\1/' | sed 'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/') ; C="echo $A | sed 's/[a-z]/$B/'" ; eval $C